# Hide mouse pointer or block movement in OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to hide the mouse pointer or prevent it from moving, globally in a background application.

I've tried "CGDisplayHideCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);", but this only seems to work with foreground applications.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885896/globally-hiding-cursor-from-background-app) seems to be my best bet, but I can't get it to compile. Specifically I get:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGSDefaultConnection()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "CGSSetConnectionProperty(int, int, __CFString const*, __CFBoolean const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o

As far as hiding the pointer, this code, using Event Taps, is the closest thing I've found so far:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

CGEventRef mouseEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
    if (type != kCGEventMouseMoved)
        return event;

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    CFMachPortRef mouseEventTap;
    CFRunLoopSourceRef mouseRunloop;

    mouseEventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, (1 << kCGEventMouseMoved), mouseEventCallback, NULL);

    if(!mouseEventTap)
        exit(1);

    mouseRunloop = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, mouseEventTap, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), mouseRunloop, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CGEventTapEnable(mouseEventTap, true);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    exit(0);
}
```

The code above blocks mouse movement events so other applications do not respond to the pointer moving over them. But it doesn't prevent the pointer itself from moving.

**EDIT**

Why do I want to do this? I'm recording mouse deltas to control another computer over the network. Applications like Synergy and Teleport do this, but the cursor is still visible on Synergy (last I checked).

Comment: Allowing this would have all kinds of consequences. You won't be able to achive it without an ugly and likely buggy hack.

Comment: Ever heard of Synergy? I want to forward mouse deltas to another computer. Having the mouse pointer remain on the screen while controlling another computer is ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to make this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885896/globally-hiding-cursor-from-background-app) compile. It turns out Synergy does hide the cursor now.

In the header file:

```
extern "C" {
     typedef int CGSConnectionID;
     CGError CGSSetConnectionProperty(CGSConnectionID cid, CGSConnectionID targetCID, CFStringRef key, CFTypeRef value);
     int _CGSDefaultConnection();
}
```

Then in the source file:

```
CFStringRef propertyString = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "SetsCursorInBackground", kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
CGSSetConnectionProperty(_CGSDefaultConnection(), _CGSDefaultConnection(), propertyString, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFRelease(propertyString);
CGDisplayHideCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
```

This seems to be the only way to do it.

I would be interested in knowing if there was a better way to temporarily disable the mouse, but still record movement.

Comment: Just confirmed, This is the correct way for anyone compiling this using a c++ file (i.e. clang++) instead of clang.